# Why is Serializable declared with fully qualified name in JDK classes?

Tags: java, serializable

It might be a bit pointless question, but while browsing sources of various JDK classes, I saw that when a class implemented the `java.io.Serializable` interface, it usually referred to it with a fully qualified name, not using an import, such as:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Is there any specific reason for this? Does this have any relation to existence of the deprecated class `sunw.io.Serializable` from the old JDK 1.0?

Comment: I belive you are right with `sunw.io.Serializable`, the authors wanted to make it clear that they mean `java.io.Serializable`. For instance `Cloneable` doesn't have a same-named counterpart in the JDK, so it would be pointless.

Comment: Ask the author of that code. Using the fully qualified name for Serializable (in my experience) is not a normal thing.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: You say that I should write an e-mail to Josh Bloch? :)

Answer (score -3):

It's generally considered poor form to just import everything willy-nilly. Using fully qualified type names (including for `java.io.Serializable` and exceptions), reduces the need for the imports and to check where those types came from.

Comment: Can you give any argument or example should anyone not import everything, especially well known JDK classes? Only cases that come in my mind where it makes sense are classes such as java.sql.Date where one would want to explicitly avoid confusion with standard `java.util.Date`. (I don't  mention static imports, they actually might cause some confusion if misused.)